# How can select a picture like a profile picture that can be changed?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Once I select a picture to **imageView** from the gallery then the size of the image changes for some reason. And when I get out of the appellation and come back again, then the picture shrinks.

That's how the beginning looks without a picture

[image]

This is how we look after selecting a picture

[image]

That's how I looked after I left and came back from the app

[image]

I do not know why it happens. I want the picture to be a profile picture and it does not look that good.

Here is my code -

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var imageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var chooseBuuton: UIButton!
    var imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()

    @IBAction func btnClicked() {

        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.savedPhotosAlbum){
            print("Button capture")

            imagePicker.delegate = self
            imagePicker.sourceType = .savedPhotosAlbum;
            imagePicker.allowsEditing = false

            self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }


    func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController!, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage!, editingInfo: NSDictionary!){
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: { () -> Void in

        })

        imageView.image = image
    }
    func webViewDidStartLoad(_ webView: UIWebView)
    {
        UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = true
    }

    func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView)
    {
        UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        let nsDocumentDirectory = FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory
        let nsUserDomainMask    = FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask
        let paths               = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(nsDocumentDirectory, nsUserDomainMask, true)
        if let dirPath          = paths.first
        {
            let imageURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: dirPath).appendingPathComponent("image.png")
            let image    = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imageURL.path)
            imageView.image = image
        }else{

            // Image not present
            // Do whatever you want to do here
        }
    }

    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

        if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
            imageView.image = image
            imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
            let path = try! FileManager.default.url(for: FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory, in: FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
            let newPath = path.appendingPathComponent("image.png") //Possibly you can Use the UserName to fetch easily User-wise
            let jpgImageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0)
            do {
                try jpgImageData!.write(to: newPath)
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }


    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

        let controller = UIImagePickerController()
        controller.delegate = self
        controller.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

Comment: *i get "Value of type 'UIImageView' has no member 'clipstobounds"'*

Comment: Try to write `imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill` for all places, where you sets image for imageView

Comment: imageView.clipsToBounds = true , imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true

Comment: set from storyboard. select imageview go attribute inspector than check the clip to bound.

Comment: * viewDidLoad yes?*

Comment: @testerbeta `imgView.clipsToBounds = true`

Comment: @testerbeta You can do it from storyboard or via code

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `clipstobounds` and `contentMode` property at both places:

**In `viewDidLoad`:**

```
    if let dirPath = paths.first {
        let imageURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: dirPath).appendingPathComponent("image.png")
        let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imageURL.path)
        imageView.image = image
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        imageView.clipsToBound = true
    } else {
        // Image not present
        // Do whatever you want to do here
    }
```

**In `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo`:**

```
    if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
        imageView.image = image
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        imageView.clipsToBound = true
```

Comment: What is the benefit of writing same thing two times.

Comment: If he want to set it from code, then he should write it with code, either he can set it from storyboard or can set `clipsToBound` from very initial in `viewDidLoad`